# Loading a Linux .so File at Java Runtime

Tags: java, dynamic-linking

I'm trying to load a linux .so file at runtime in Java, but I'm getting an UnsatisfiedLinkError.  I'm passing in the -Djava.library.path=/Users/tom/codebase/jni/dist VM argument when running the below java main from my Test.class.  The libSample.so file is in the /Users/tom/codebase/jni/dist directory.  Any ideas?  Thanks!

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.library.path")); 
                //prints /Users/tom/codebase/jni/dist
        System.loadLibrary("Sample");
    }

}
```

**VM Argument:**

```
-Djava.library.path=/Users/tom/codebase/jni/dist
```

**Exception:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no Sample in java.library.path
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1758)
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:823)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1045)
at Test.main(Test.java:9)
```

I also tried to use  try the direct approach (using System.load) and got the below results if these help any Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /Users/tom/codebase/jni/dist/libSample.so: no suitable image found. Did find: /Users/tom/codebase/jni/dist/libCiscoEnergyWiseJni.so: unknown file type, first eight bytes: 0x7F 0x45 0x4C 0x46 0x01 0x01 0x01 0x00

Comment: Does your library depend on another library called libCiscoEnergyWiseJni ?

Comment: (if so, you need to append :/the/folder/where/its/installed to the end of java.library.path)

Comment: no sorry that was a typo...fixed now

Comment: I am facing the exact same problem. Were you able to find a solution?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Libraries on Linux are often named in the pattern `libXXX.so`, and I believe Java follows that convention. So `System.loadLibrary("Sample")` may be looking for `libSample.so`. You can verify this by making a quick test program to call [`System.mapLibraryName`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#mapLibraryName%28java.lang.String%29) and checking the output.

To resolve the issue, assuming this is in fact the problem you're having, you can either rename your library file or use `System.load` (not `System.loadLibrary`), which will load the library specified by the exact filename you pass it, without any transformations. The latter method is not portable across platforms, though.

Comment: Thanks for the response David. The file name is actually libSample.so, I've edited my first question...sorry for the confusion

Comment: I did try the direct approach (using System.load) and got the below results if these help any Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /Users/tom/codebase/jni/dist/libSample.so:  no suitable image found.  Did find:  /Users/tom/codebase/jni/dist/libCiscoEnergyWiseJni.so: unknown file type, first eight bytes: 0x7F 0x45 0x4C 0x46 0x01 0x01 0x01 0x00

Comment: @c12: I suggest editing that information into the question for other answerers.

Comment: THANK YOU, really, 2 hours and 10 post later I found the solution. The "libXXX" prefix.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
Runtime.getRuntime().load(resource);
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue in Linux and solved by setting the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=<Lib File Path>:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH.
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

```
public class Demo 
{
    static
    {
        try 
        {
            System.load("/home/libsofile.so");
        }
        catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e) 
        {
            System.err.println("Native code library failed to load.\n" + e);
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```